# how do add a single entry for two tables using linq to entities

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

[image]I have  table called

```
                    product

                    product_id
                    product_Name
                    product_Price
                    product_Description
                    product_image
                    category_id

another table      category
                   category_id
                   category_name
```

i have a new form with textboxes like

```
                                  txtprodname
                                  txtproddescrip
                                  txtproductprice
                                  picturebox1
                                  txtcategoryname
```

i am trying to add the new product to producttable by using following code

i am using entity framework..

```
     public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
        byte[] bit = null;

        bit = imageToByteArray(image);

        product pd = new product();
        pd.product_Name = txtprodname.Text;
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtproductprice.Text);
        pd.product_Price = price;
        pd.product_Description = txtproddescrip.Text;           
        pd.product_Image = bit;
        tsgentity.AddToproducts(pd);
        tsgentity.SaveChanges();
        this.Close();       

   }
```

I am trying to add new product to the product table .. but i dont have any idea how to add the category name to category table .......by using linq

how do i add category name to category table and update the product table with category name that i  have entered...

how do update the category id in product table with this name entered along with the new product added to the product table

can any one help on this ....

i am using winforms .....and c# language

this is my entity diagram....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to first check if the entered category already exists and want to reuse it if it does. I also assume `tsgentity` is your DbContext:

```
string categoryName = category_name.Text;
Category category = tsgentity.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.category_name == categoryName );
if (category == null)
    category = new Category() { category_name = categoryName };

pd.category = category;
tsgentity.Categories.Add(category);
```

The above code should be executed before you run `tsgentity.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: I have category description textbox also do i need to do same for category description also..

Comment: That really depends on what you're trying to achieve... If somebody adds a product, does he really want to change/update it's category's description? Ask for precise requirements.

Comment: hi.. i amm not able got the pd.category... before this line  tsgentity.Categories.Add(category);

Comment: Show us your ``product`` and ``category`` classes.

Comment: see my product and category classes entity diagram

Comment: In your ``product`` entity, ``category_Id`` should be a _navigation property_, and not just an ``int `` property.

Comment: I recommend digging more into Entity Framework from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you have mapped everything correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var pd = new Product();
//Set properties of product

var c = new Category { Name = txtCategoryName.Text, Description = txtCategoryDescription.Text };
pd.Category = c;

tsgentity.AddToproducts(pd);
tsgentity.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @hi abbas is there any possiblity to specify the foreign key to table using entity

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not really clear to me. What do you want to achieve?