# specifying the foreign key to the table programmatically by using fluentapi 

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

hi is there any possibility to assign a foriegnkey to table using entity ....

pls see this question for clarification..    [how do add a single entry for two tables using linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119764/how-do-add-a-single-entry-for-two-tables-using-linq-to-entities)

let me explain clearly.....

```
      i have a product table    product_id
                                product_name 
                                product_description
                                category_id


                                category table
                                category_id
                                category_name
```

unfortunately it is not posssible to specify the category_id as a foreign key at the time of creating table the entity table it self taken the category_id as a column not as a foreign key

so.. i want to specify this one as foreign key so.. is it possible to specify as a foreign key by programmatically 
 can any one have sample code for specifying foreignkey using fluent api

Comment: huh? what do you mean by programmatically??? Sql, front-end asp.net php???

Comment: i am using c# and mysql and entity relation ship ...

Comment: @laurence like specifying the navigation property in entity ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using EntityFramework 4.1, you can use the [Fluent API](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx), which allows you to specify key names and other association properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a sample, of how I did that in EF 4.1 CodeFirst. I think, you can use very similar aproach.

```
public class P
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<P> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<P>().HasRequired(p => p.CategoryId).WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

In the OnModelCreating, you tell context, how want to set relations, even if there are no such relations in DB.